# We could not add the account Visual Studio 2015 (Azure)

Tags: c#, azure, exception, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service

I published my web app using Azure, but each time when I try to login I get the following exception:

[image: exception]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Visual Studio Credential Errors on Microsoft Azure Account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818924/microsoft-visual-studio-credential-errors-on-microsoft-azure-account)