# Microsoft Visual Studio Credential Errors on Microsoft Azure Account

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I was trying to deploy my web application to Microsoft Azure and as I enter my credentials for my Microsoft account, this error popped up and I'm unable to seek the solution to solve. However, I tried logging in through Microsoft Visual Studio itself and get the same error message as well

[Error In TextForm]

We could not add the account [myemail] user_interaction_required : One of two conditions was encountered: 1. The PromptBehavior.Never flag was passed, but the constraint could not be honored, because user interaction was required. 2. An error occurred during a silent web authentication that prevented the http authentication flow from completing in a short enough time frame

[image: Error Description]

May I know what details I need to check in order to solve the following error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

1. *Remove* the existing account from Visual Studio
2. Close Visual Studio
3. Open a developer command prompt
4. Type `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`
5. Restart Visual Studio
6. Try and enter you credentials

Worked for me.

Comment: got the same problem, buy it didn't help me

Comment: Helped me - but when restarting Visual Studio (step 5) I got some errors, I had to reinstall some packages (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebEssentials20153 and https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebExtensionPack)

Comment: the command has to be used in the following folder: \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE>

Comment: This did not work for me, unfortunately.  Also should be advised on just what all this does before trying it, maybe take a backup first - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823385/what-does-visual-studio-devenv-exe-resetuserdata-do-exactly

Comment: Nevermind, it must have taken some time to take effect.  Still might be good to try a backup first, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I recently left a company.
They had referenced my personal account for some reason in their Azure Active Directory and locked down the account.
I could determine I was still part of their directory from the azure portal, on the right after clicking on the user name their directory was here among others.
Just contacted then to remove the reference to my account which looks like this if your email is johndoe@hotmail.com : johndoe_hotmail.com#EST#@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com

Answer (score 0):

I removed the Users from Azure Active Directory group which were not having any subscriptions, and it works!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
 1. Remove existing account
 2. Restart
 3. Add account